# Ensure endDate equal to or later than startDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a table in which I need to ensure that `startDate` is not later than `endDate`.

Either date can be updated so the rules have to apply regardless if `startDate` or `endDate` (or both) are entered/modified.

Is it better to use triggers, stored procedures or something else? Any sample syntax is appreciated.

Comment: If this is part of a .net, php, coldfusion, whatever application, you could use application code to prevent the update from being attempted.

Comment: @DanBracuk but then what if a user runs an ad hoc update outside of the application? Data integrity logic should be as close to the data as possible - if you want to add redundant logic elsewhere to capture it earlier, great, but the further away from the data it is, the less effective it will ever be...

Answer (score 5):

Use a check constraint. Much simpler than a trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo
(
  StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
  EndDate   DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CheckEndLaterThanStart CHECK (EndDate >= StartDate)
);
```

If the table already exists:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo
  ADD CONSTRAINT CheckEndLaterThanStart
  CHECK (EndDate >= StartDate);
```

If you try to insert a start date later than the end date, you'll get:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CheckEndLaterThanStart". The conflict occurred in database "AdventureWorks2012", table "dbo.foo".
>   The statement has been terminated.